# Issue with Robots.txt file verification

Tags: robots.txt

I am using a really simple robots.txt file for our portal which is as follows

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /robots.txt

The issue is, when I use an online verifier and point it to the live copy of my robots.txt file its displaying this strange extra character and error

```
Line 1 ï»¿User-agent: *

This line doesn't follow a correct syntax. The correct syntax is: : , where "field" can be "User-agent" or "Disallow". Please refer to Robots Exclusion Standard page for more informations.
```

please note the strange character its showing just before user agent. Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be byte-order marker (BOM) when you're saving as utf maybe? If so save as ASCII.

Comment: Please post it as answer, thats exactly what happened. Saved the file as ANSI and it was all fine.

Comment: Google's robot.txt tester should stress a little more on this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What could be causing this is that you have a BOM (Byte Order Marker) at the start of the file since you are saving in UTF. If so, the easiest way to correct this is to resave the `robots.txt` file in ASCII.

Comment: Does notepad does this?  Give the ability to save in ASCII?